# Restkit: How do I get these JSON values from a website

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I am new to Restkit and basically need to retrieve these values from the nsurl website moo/api.com (example nsurl). What will be the best method for this.  Already claim the properties and did the object mapping. Now need help return the values in nslog.  The class is view controller. Any help would be appreciated.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* ID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* Text;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* author;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Terms class]];
    [articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"ID": @"ID",
        @"Text": @"Text",
        @"author": @"author"
     }];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an introduction to RestKit, follow [this link to the official wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki). There are several articles covering [Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping), posting/retrieving data and so on.

The following example is taken from the aforementioned wiki:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"__YOUR_KEYPATH__" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"__YOUR_URL__"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];

[objectRequestOperation start];
```